# Converting Strings to Template Literals in ES6

Tags: javascript, templates, ecmascript-6

Suppose I have a string like `"${a + b}"`, say read from JSON, that I'd like interpreted as an ES6 template literal. I thought something like this might work:

```
var x = {"add": "${a + b}"};
var a = 10, b = 20;
alert(`${x.add}`);
```

But this alerts as `${a + b}`, so it just does one level of substitution.

Tried being clever by interpreting it again:

```
var a = 10, b = 20;
var x = {"add": "${a + b}"};
var i = `${x.add}`;
alert(`${i}`);
```

This still alerts as `${a + b}`.

Tried being even more clever:

```
var a = 10, b = 20;
var x = {"add": "${a} + ${b}"};
var i = `${x.add}`;
alert(`${i}`);
```

This alerts as `${a} + ${b}`.

Starting with a string, e.g. `"${a + b}"`, is there any way to have this evaluated to completion as if it were a template literal? Ideally without `eval`!

Comment: They're template *literals*, not template strings. It's true that if you don't use a tag function on them, they end up creating strings (but if you use a tag function on them, they may not).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Cleaned it up a bit. Hoping the wording is better now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they aren't recursive.

If your starting point is a *string* containing those placeholders, as far as I know there is no template compiler function. There's `eval`, of course; [insert all the usual caveats about using `eval` — only with content you trust, not if you can avoid it, etc., etc. — here].

So for instance:

```js
"use strict";
var x = {"add": "${a + b}"};
var a = 10, b = 20;
console.log(eval("`" + x.add + "`"));
```

Comment: I get it as a string literal though, for example, `"${a + b}"`, read from a JSON source, so no solution?

Comment: @YiminRong: If you receive the template *as a string*, I'm not aware of any template compiler function, no. You could, of course, use `eval` (with all the usual caveats about using `eval`).